# Yo sync copy possibility for files

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator, yo

Is there any possibility to use this.copy in yo generator in sync mode?
I need my sub-generators to be invoked only after all the files from parent generator has been copied.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

this.fs.commit(function(){});

to write the in-memory files to disk.